# Cordova failed to run Java -version

Tags: java, android-sdk

When I run in the terminal `Java -version`, the output is:

```
java version "1.7.0_95"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.4) (7u95-2.6.4-0ubuntu0.15.04.1)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 24.95-b01, mixed mode)
```

But when I run:

```
~/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/5.1.0/package/bin/check_reqs
```

It returns:

```
{ [CordovaError: Failed to run "java -version", make sure that you have a JDK installed.
You can get it from: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads.
]
  name: 'CordovaError',
  message: 'Failed to run "java -version", make sure that you have a JDK installed.\nYou can get it from: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads.\n',
  code: 0,
  context: undefined }
```

I am using Node.js version 5.6.0, and I am able to run Android sdk and start the program `avd`.
I try to add this:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/i386:$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/i386/client
```

but the problem remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem: i was missing the jdk installation. I only had the jre.

```
apt-get install python-software-properties python g++ make ant openjdk-7-jre openjdk-7-jdk
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using and unsupported version you can install the new version of JDK and it will be up and running.

This error tells you the issue:

```
"make sure that you have a JDK installed.
You" can get it from: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads."
```

**Installation of the JDK on Linux Platforms**

This procedure installs the Java Development Kit (JDK) for 64-bit Linux, using an archive binary file (.tar.gz).

These instructions use the following file:

```
jdk-8uversion-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

Before the file can be downloaded, you may need too accept the license agreement. The archive binary can be installed by anyone (not only root users), in any location that you can write to. However, only the root user can install the JDK into the system location.

Change directory to the location where you would like the JDK to be installed, then move the .tar.gz archive binary to the current directory.

Unpack the tarball and install the JDK.

```
% tar zxvf jdk-8uversion-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

The Java Development Kit files are installed in a directory called **jdk1.8.0_version** in the current directory.

Delete the **.tar.gz** file if you want to save disk space.
Or use

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

[You can install the 32 version here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/linux_jdk.html#BJFCDAIB)
[Reference:](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) Oracle